# golang Confusing code RabbitMq forever blocked ！？

Tags: go, rabbitmq, channel

I found an interesting piece of code when using rabbitMQ

```
forever := make(chan bool)

    go func() {
        for d := range msgs {
    
            log.Printf("Received a message: %s", d.Body)

        }
    }()

    log.Printf(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C")
    <-forever
```

This is a block of code ，
In fact, in normal mode,
this would cause a deadlock error,
Like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iCWz.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiS66.png)

But when I import rabbitMQ package , this code does not cause an error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ka2ff.png)
Why is that? I'm confused.
Thanks for  answer!

Expect someone to explain

Comment: => https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide a description to the image you've uploaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using rabbitmq, the `msgs` variable is a receiving channel of type `<-chan amqp.Delivery` - [see docs](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/streadway/amqp#Channel.Consume) i.e a channel receive messages. The range loop is enters the body each time a message appears. This is a useful control sequence - block the main goroutine whilst the worker awaits and processes messages. There is no deadlock in this case as rabbitmq connection will send messages down the `msgs` chan when appropriate.

In earlier code, when you connect to the queue and instantiate the `msgs` channel, the amqp package çreates another goroutine in the background to send messages down the `msgs` channel.

```golang
msgs, err := ch.Consume(
  q.Name, // queue
  "",     // consumer
  true,   // auto-ack
  false,  // exclusive
  false,  // no-local
  false,  // no-wait
  nil,    // args
)
```

This is unlike the deadlock examples provided, where there is no additional go-routines to send messages down the `forever` channel. The goroutine goes to sleep and there is no chance of it being awakened. It is a deadlock.